# ansible syntax error to set tag in playbook under roles

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

Team, 
I tried several combinations nothing worked. how to set tag under role in playbook?

```
  roles:
    - 3_validations_on_ssh
      tags: [test]
```

```
    - 3_validations_on_ssh
      tags: test
```

output:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    - 3_validations_on_ssh
      tags: test
          ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I had to use role

```
  roles:
    - role: 3_validations_on_ssh
      tags: test
```

but is there a way to use `-role` like what I tried in my question?